# @RefreshScope is not working as expected- SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have configured a bean in @RefreshScope in a Spring boot application and overriding the datasource configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Autowired
private DbConfig dbConfig;

@Bean
@Primary
@RefreshScope
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource=new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:file:~/spring-boot-h2-db");
    dataSource.setUsername(dbConfig.getUsername());        
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(dbConfig.getMaxPoolSize());
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    return dataSource;
  }
}
```

And DbConfig:

```
@PropertySource("file:/Users/rarifi/temp/application.properties")
@RefreshScope
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(
    prefix = "spring.datasource"
)
public class DbConfig {

@Value("username")
private String username;

private int maxPoolSize;

public int getMaxPoolSize() {
    return maxPoolSize;
}

public void setMaxPoolSize(int maxPoolSize) {
    this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
}

@Autowired
private StandardEnvironment environment;

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }
}
```

And I call the refreshEndpoint.refresh after I update the configuration property files in another piece of code. During refresh the code enters the getDatasource but still pointing to the same properties used during the initialization. What needs to be changed so that, it reads the changed properties? The properties are updated at runtime if they are not defined as @RefreshScope

Comment: It won't reload the file it will one do the binding again. As it isn't reloaded nothing has changed. You would need to replace the property source in the environment after changing the content of the file. Then it would work.

Comment: @M. Deinum I have not included that piece of code which reloads the file. I can see the changes at runtime when I do not use the RefreshScope, but the problem is the Datasource bean is not refreshed. On the other hand when I use RefreshScope it tries to refresh the bean but the properties are not loaded at runtime and Datasource is refreshed with the same initilaized values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the issue. It was not related to the @RefreshScope annotation but to the way that properties were reloaded. I changed the @PropertySource from @PropertySource("file:/Users/rarifi/temp/application.properties") to @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") and it started to work properly. Also it works when I set the location in the spring.config.location as an environement variable when running the application

Answer (score 0):

You need to move @RefreshScope annotation on class context.

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope

public class DataSourceConfig {
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. When I try @RefreshScope at class level, it does not go through getDatasource method at all. I have tried multiple combination but none of them is working

Comment: I've taken a look and I saw that you @Value("username")  won't be able to match with some property configuration.. You need to change it to @Value("${username}")

Comment: Correct. I still have the issue even if I change it.  What do you think causes the issue?

Comment: Could you please share us your code on github? so I can help you much better. :)

Comment: Thanks alot Jonathan, I was going to send you the github project but I found the issues finally. It was not related to the @RefreshScope annotation but to the way that properties were reloaded. I changed the PropertySource from @PropertySource("file:/Users/rarifi/temp/application.properties") to @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") and when reloading the resource and it worked properly. Also it works when I define the spring.config.location as an environement variable when running the application